# dplyr packaging refering to column names

Tags: r, dplyr

Hi I'm new to `dplyr package`. I've extracted data from excel that has column names such as `Q1'15`, `Q2'15`, `Q3'15`, `Q4'15`. I'm having a hard time referring to these columns. Let's say extracted data are stored in a dataframe called `data`, and here's my code:

```
new_data <- data %>% 
group_by(Application_Name,Classification) %>% 
summarise("2015" = sum(Q1'15:Q2'15))
```

I tried using `names(data[19])` with no luck.

Other than replacing column names, are there any better ways to refer to these columns?

Comment: I guess you need `summarise_each`

Comment: You'll need to put backticks around those column names, or remove the `'` marks.  And/or `names(data)[19]` instead of `names(data[19])`

Comment: @YuanH DO you need to get the sum of individual column by group or the aggregated sum of 'Q1'15:Q2'15'?

Comment: I'd recommend reading [tidy data](http://vita.had.co.nz/papers/tidy-data.html)